# Payment method does not show

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, checkout-page

I tried to add (enable) new payment method on the Magento 2 but unfortunately the enabled option does not shown on the checkout page, here is my checkout page snapshot:

[image]

**Here is my Enable Payment Method:**
[image]

My Question is how to show my new Payment Method on the checkout page?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: it should be in your method renderer js. double check from there

Comment: I am sorry I don't get what you say, could you explain more in detail?

Comment: I'm talking about the js file from this location, `view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\method-renderer`

Comment: I think your installed Payment module is broken, try to contact the Vendor

Comment: mhmh yeah I think so, I will ask the Module developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibility**

For the sake of testing, toggle the Enable Onepage Checkout in `Config > Sales > Checkout` to see if the payment methods show up on the two-step checkout.

In my case, the toggle got flipped so that, although `Enable Onepage Checkout was set to No`, I was getting the One Page Checkout view on the frontend. After flipping the setting, I was able to see all the correct Payment Methods on the second step of the checkout process (as expected).